# invalid XPath expression postgresql

Tags: xml, postgresql

I am trying to read from a xml and insert that value in a temporary table which I can return via postgres function. I am getting an error 'invalid XPath expression' when I try to execute the function. I am not sure how I am providing the incorrect path in XMLTABLE. My original xml is very huge with lists of SolutionRatingEntity tags and I want to display the childs of each of this tag as a single row. For sake of simplicity and issue replication I have only provided one SolutionRatingEntity tag. Can you please guide where I went wrong . Thanks in advance.

```
create or replace function xml()
returns table(Id integer
,CriteriaName character varying
,Level INTeger
,SolutionName character varying     
,ParentName character varying     
,SuperParentName character varying     
,Rating character varying     
,InScopeFlag INTEGER    
,BusinessPriority character varying     
,NodeNumber character varying)
as $$
declare
xmlvalue text := '<ArrayOfSolutionRatingEntity xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<SolutionRatingEntity>
<Id>0</Id>
<IsActive>true</IsActive><LastModifiedBy>SYSTEM</LastModifiedBy><LastModifiedOn>2022-09-30</LastModifiedOn>
<CriteriaName /><SolutionName>NAme</SolutionName><ParentName /><Level>0</Level><SolutionRating /><SuperParentName />
<InScopeFlag>false</InScopeFlag><IsProcessNode>false</IsProcessNode></SolutionRatingEntity></ArrayOfSolutionRatingEntity>';
begin
drop if exists tempCriteiaRating ;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tempCriteiaRating (    
Id integer NOT NULL  GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 2147483647 CACHE 1 )
,CriteriaName character varying
,Level INTeger
,SolutionName character varying     
,ParentName character varying     
,SuperParentName character varying     
,Rating character varying     
,InScopeFlag INTEGER    
,BusinessPriority character varying     
,NodeNumber character varying     
);

with data as ( 
select xmlvalue::xml val)
INSERT INTO tempCriteiaRating (    
CriteriaName    
,Level    
,SolutionName    
,ParentName    
,SuperParentName    
,Rating    
,InScopeFlag    
,BusinessPriority    
,NodeNumber    
)    
SELECT 
d.CriteriaName    
,d.Level    
,d.SolutionName    
,d.ParentName    
,d.SuperParentName    
,d.Rating    
,d.InScopeFlag    
,d.BusinessPriority    
,d.NodeNumber      
FROM data x,
XMLTABLE('/ArrayOfSolutionRatingEntity/SolutionRatingEntity'
PASSING val
COLUMNS
CriteriaName character varying PATH 'CriteriaName',
Level integer PATH 'level',
SolutionName integer PATH 'Solution Name',
ParentName character varying PATH 'Parent Name',
SuperParentName character varying PATH 'SuperParent Name',
Rating character varying PATH 'Solution Rating',
InScopeFlag INTEGER PATH 'InScopeFlag',
BusinessPriority character varying PATH 'BusinessPriority',
NodeNumber character varying PATH 'NodeNumber') as d;

return query
select * from tempCriteiaRating ;
end;
$$
language plpgsql
```

Answer (score 2):

Tags may not contain spaces, so the XPath `'Solution Name'` is invalid (and wouldn't match anything as the tag is `SolutionName`). You need to specify it without the space.

But you have some more problems.

- `SolutionName` does not contain a number, so that should be text
- `InScopeFlag` contains the value `false`, so that should probably be a `boolean`, not an integer.

The whole temporary table is completely unnecessary as is PL/pgSQL actually.

```
create or replace function xml()
  returns table(Id integer
                ,criterianame character varying
                ,level integer
                ,solutionname character varying     
                ,parentname character varying     
                ,superparentname character varying     
                ,rating character varying     
                ,inscopeflag boolean
                ,businesspriority character varying     
                ,nodenumber character varying)
as
$$
    with data (val) as (
    values (
      '<ArrayOfSolutionRatingEntity xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
          <SolutionRatingEntity>
              <Id>0</Id>
              <IsActive>true</IsActive>
              <LastModifiedBy>SYSTEM</LastModifiedBy>
              <LastModifiedOn>2022-09-30</LastModifiedOn>
              <CriteriaName/>
              <SolutionName>NAme</SolutionName>
              <ParentName/>
              <Level>0</Level>
              <SolutionRating/>
              <SuperParentName/>
              <InScopeFlag>false</InScopeFlag>
              <IsProcessNode>false</IsProcessNode>
          </SolutionRatingEntity>
      </ArrayOfSolutionRatingEntity>'::xml)
    )
    SELECT row_number() over () as id, 
           d.*
    FROM data x,
    XMLTABLE('/ArrayOfSolutionRatingEntity/SolutionRatingEntity'
              PASSING val
              COLUMNS CriteriaName text PATH 'CriteriaName',
                      Level integer PATH 'level',
                      SolutionName text PATH 'SolutionName',
                      ParentName text PATH 'ParentName',
                      SuperParentName text PATH 'SuperParentName',
                      Rating text PATH 'SolutionRating',
                      InScopeFlag boolean PATH 'InScopeFlag',
                      BusinessPriority text PATH 'BusinessPriority',
                      NodeNumber text PATH 'NodeNumber') as d;
$$
language sql;
```